# How do I get ServiceStack DLLs (Not from Nuget)?

Tags: servicestack

I'm a subscrption customer but I can't login to ServiceStack forum to ask question because of this message "Your account hasn't been approved yet. You will be notified by email when you are ready to log in.". It've been weeks and I didn't see any notification email from ServiceStack.

I don't think I'm going to renew my subscription since I have little use of the software. I'll like to get all the .dll that is currently covered under my subscription and license to use since I already pay for it. Is there a way to get all the .dlls without using nuget? is there a place for download?

Please response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account Approval should be automatic when Signing up to the forums with the **exact** email used to create an Account with ServiceStack. You can find [ServiceStack's email on the FAQ](https://servicestack.net/pricing#faq) to investigate any issues.

The official .dll's for each ServiceStack release are only published on NuGet. You can download the NuGet packages without using NuGet by downloading them directly from the nuget.org website by clicking on **Download package** link for each package, e.g:

[image]

Direct Link: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ServiceStack/5.8.0

Then you can access the dll's by renaming the extension to .zip, e.g:

```
servicestack.5.8.0.zip
```

Then you can unzip it to access both the **.NET Framework** and **.NET Standard 2.0** (.NET Core) dll's.

You're also able to download a snapshot of the source code for each Release:

- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Azure/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/releases
- https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin/releases

Where you can build the **.sln** Solution in each repository to generate your own .dll's from source.

Your license lets you use any version of ServiceStack released before your License Expires.